# Spring - MongoDB very slow on request

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, controller

I've been running a small Java SpringFramework project with a MongoDB for a while now. While it is not running on the most powerful hardware it's been behaving very slow as of late with one particular Collection.

The particular Collection of the database has around 30 entries with an average size of 1.5KB. Most other collections are smaller and much faster.

I have narrowed it down to the database as making the collection empty speeds it up completely.

The logs confuse me though. When I request my webpage this is my log (running on slightly better hardware then my server, which is even slower):

```
...
2018-07-23 13:34:08.176 DEBUG 12736 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/employees/active]
2018-07-23 13:34:08.177 DEBUG 12736 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /employees/active
2018-07-23 13:34:08.178 DEBUG 12736 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public java.lang.String be.ccdestrycker.callcentermanager.controller.EmployeeController.showActiveEmployees(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)]
2018-07-23 13:34:08.178 DEBUG 12736 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/employees/active] is: -1
2018-07-23 13:34:09.725  INFO 12736 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] b.c.c.CallCenterManagerApplication       : TIMING - controller start
2018-07-23 13:34:09.747  INFO 12736 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] b.c.c.CallCenterManagerApplication       : TIMING - controller end
2018-07-23 13:34:09.748 DEBUG 12736 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*])
2018-07-23 13:34:09.748 DEBUG 12736 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView@5d0cd3ba] based on requested media type 'text/html'
...
```

The log is much longer but there is no other slowdown beyond this point.

The longest period where it hangs is right before my controller's code(in the log right above my first 'TIMER' log) is doing the actual query. Or is the controller not executed sequentially? This is my requestmapping :

```java
@RequestMapping(value = {"/employees/active"})
public String showActiveEmployees(final ModelMap model) {
    this.loggerService.info("TIMING - controller start");
    model.addAttribute("allEmployees", this.employeeService.findAllActive());
    this.loggerService.info("TIMING - controller end");
    return "employees-list";
}
```

So I'm confused as to where exactly is the slowdown and how it is related to the MongoDB collection even though the query is not even executed at that point. And if there is anything I can improve upon it.

Here is the Employee class incase it's necessary.

```java
public class Employee {

    @Id
    public String id;

    public List<Skill> skills = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<EmployeeLanguage> employeeLanguages = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<EmployeeAbsence> employeeAbsences = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<EmployeeEvaluation> employeeEvaluations = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<EmployeeNote> employeeNotes = new ArrayList<>();
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String code;
    public int peopleOnBehalf;
    public String maritalStatus;
    public String nationality;
    public String address;
    public int postalCode;
    public String town;
    public String phoneNumber;
    public String email;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    public LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    public String placeOfBirth;
    public String landOfBirth;
    public String idCardNumber;
    public String nationalRegisterNumber;
    public String bankAccountNumber;
    public String comment;
    public boolean active = true;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    public LocalDate startDate;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    public LocalDate endDate;
    public String unactiveReason;
    public LocalDateTime dateCreation;
    public LocalDateTime dateLastEdit;
```

my service:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

   ...

    public List<Employee> findAllActive() {
        return this.employeeRepository.findByActive(true);
    }
}
```

my repository:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends MongoRepository<Employee, String> {

    List<Employee> findByActive(boolean active);

}
```

Comment: Can you show your employeeService class?

Comment: added service and repository to my post above. My service also has a whole bunch of other methods but I figured those weren't important here so I omitted them.

Comment: I assume EmployeeLanguage, EmployeeAbsence etc are entities as well? The one thing I can advice you is to optimize your entityEmployee . Either split it in parts or properly optimize it. One article showing what I have in mind: https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/how-to-use-jpa-correctly-to-avoid-complaints-of-a-slow-application/

Comment: If you mean entities as in stored on the database in separate Collections no they are not. The are completely stored solely in the Employee object. Is that why it is so slow cause Employee holds too many attributes and lists within it? I'll look into that then! So rather do more query to separate collections then one to a big one. Thanks

Comment: To give an answer here, I ended up following your advice to split it. All my sub entities are now in their own repositories and have simple ID links. Speed has not been an issue since.